# Add label from SPSS as column name in R

Tags: r, spss

I try to import an SPSS file (.sav) into R. I used:

```
library(forigin)
read.spss("file.sav", to.data.frame = TRUE, use.value.labels = TRUE)
```

For the original data Label is coded like "Q8A_10 - some text". See the picture below (i.e. "Language" in the first line):

[image]

But the column name which I get from `read.spss` says just "Q8A_10" (i.e. without the text). How can I get the complete Label from SPSS as column name.

If I `view()` the data frame it´s OK,

[image]

but not if I use `glimpse()` or `str()`

```
library(dplyr)

file %>%
select(1:2) %>%
head()

  RESPID        SAMPLE
1    524 Client Sample
2   1362 Client Sample
3   1872 Client Sample
4   1894 Client Sample
5   2063 Client Sample
6   2077 Client Sample
```

Comment: This leads to the same result.

Comment: This is intended and expected behavior in both the `foreign` as well as the `haven`-package. As you see, "Language" is the label of column "q02". Those labels are still present as labels when the data is loaded in R, but they are not part of the columnname (which is neither the case in SPSS). Using `lapply(df, attr, "label")` will return the labels of the respective columns.

Comment: I read and tried this already. If I try this I get only "Q8A_10" but without the text.

Comment: Could you also inlcude a screendump of when you do `View(df)`?